# PgSQL, Django - history for table with many fields - how to organize properly?

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm new to Django and not very experienced with PgSQL. I need to create a table with about 10 fields. Thing is that each item I constantly changing and I need to keep a history of changes for each field. For now, I found several solutions for this purpose, but I concerned:

1) https://github.com/arkhipov/temporal_tables

Relays on DB and triggers. The concern is that history kept in an additional single table, so each time 1 field is changed it will create a new history record with 9 surplus fields and I intend to show history per field, not per item, so data amount will grow 9 times faster with no purpose. Or DB will optimize it? Also, have images, that naturally have only on/off datetime history.

2) https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history

Better, than first, because has integration with Django. Also have lots of features, like Custom history_date(i have lots of snapshots already in files). But still the same concern as 1

3) Manually create the main table with ID and make relation tables for each of fields. Looks like a nightmare for managing. Also, need to perform lots of joins to get current full record(Can Django work with VIEW?)

So can you advice better solution? Or maybe my thoughts about lots of surplus data is wrong and I should stop bothering?

Answer (score 0):

Normally PG optimizes very well the performance.

It really depends on how much data you will store. However, can't you make an additional table for every change you do *per row*, not *per field*? What is the impact on doing this way?

But, you can work with persistence of the history too. For example, only store the last 3 versions of each field. This will minimize your data, but you need to manage it by code, or make a trigger/procedure. Adding to this, you always can make a backup and store locally/cloud if you want to retrieve it someday.

If you stick to the first option in working with the records per field, I suggest working with django integration, but it's up to you really.

Comment: "However, can't you make an additional table for every change you do per row, not per field" - 
That is no. 3 option. Besides complicated dev and management, I will have to make everything from scratch.
The whole point is to store the entire history. It can be years of history. I also asked about if PG does data duplication optimization, or not?